# Django how to pass an id of pagination and model id?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Thankyou i am getting a problem.I am using pagination in url passing a page id and want to pass my model driver id also. if a page is at 1 the url is

```
         *url(r'^rentacar/list/$', extension_views.rentacar_list),*
```

but after user go to next page the url is:

```
              *url(r'^rentacar/list/(\d+)/$', extension_views.rentacar_list),*
```

but i actually want to do is to reference driver id in the url that i am trying to pass.

What am trying to do is to get driver id and page# in my url. how do i go about doing this? and how can i change my views and achieve it whereas its running through pagination

**Views.py**

```
@csrf_protect
def rentacar_list(request, page_number=1):

    all_cars = Car.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    if menu_config.menu_item_rentacar_list_show_unavailable == 0:
        all_cars = all_cars.exclude(car_available=0)
    else:
        all_cars = all_cars

    cars_page = Paginator(all_cars, menu_config.menu_item_rentacar_list_pagination)
    args['cars'] = cars_page.page(page_number)
    template = Template.objects.get(template_default__exact=1)    
    template_page = template.template_alias + str("/rentacar/rentacar_cars_list.html")   
    return render(request, template_page, args)
```

**Urls.py**

```
url(r'^rentacar/list/$', extension_views.rentacar_list),
url(r'^rentacar/list/(\d+)/$', extension_views.rentacar_list),
```

but i want to achieve :

```
url(r'^rentacar/list/driver/id/$', extension_views.rentacar_list),
url(r'^rentacar/list/(\d+)/driver/id/$', extension_views.rentacar_list),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your driver id shouldnt in urlpath，you can transmit data in url parameters，for example：

```
yourhost/rentacar/list/<page_id>?driver=<driver_id>
```

get driver_id form `request`, for example:

```
driver_id = request.GET.get('driver', None)
```

last, you can refactor view by django ListView which has buildin pagination function,here is django ListView documnet  [django listview](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)

**example**

url.py

```
url(r'^rentacar/list/(\d+)/$', extension_views.rentacar_list),
```

views.py

```
def you_view(request, page_number):
    driver_id = request.GET.get('driver', None)
```

your request url

```
127.0.0.1/rentacar/list/1?driver=2
```

Comment: I didnt get it ? i just have to pass as a request in it ?

Comment: you url dont need change，just add driver after ?. In your view, you can get you dirver data in `request.GET`

Comment: i add a example, try it

Comment: Thankyou its working. i think it will be new question . how do i pass this driver id to next page

Comment: for eg driver 2 is john and he books a car from list . my car is passing through url but i want that driver also which driver booked the car .

Comment: url(r'^rentacar/car/(\d+)/driver/(\d+)/$', extension_views.rentacar_car),  this is my next page . where  i am passing the driver and car in template as a hidden field. its not automatically getting . while i have to write in url on my own . like this . http://127.0.0.1:8000/rentacar/car/1/driver/1/

Comment: i think you should have account function. every driver is a user.they can login and book the car.

Comment: yeah but  the driver is registered through a form after that  send a link to the drivers with thier id in it .

Comment: but i want to use it as by passing it throgh form

Comment: i dont get what your said.but if your driver logged in, you can simply get user by `request.user`. here is django account document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/

Comment: what form do you mean, django form or html form?

Comment: no i am not using a log in . i am just register him by sending him link of django form . after that our employe view the form and verify it . after that send an email with the link . the link of cars .

Comment: sorry, i get sleep last night. If you post your request via form, you can get form data from `request.Post`.here is django document ,you can read it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django